# Very slow with motion server - Raspberry Pi B

Tags: raspbian, video, motion

Yesterday i configured "motion" on my old Raspberry Pi 1 B version with Raspberry camera module. It work all but i have a problem: when i connected at my raspberry with his ip adress, i see the movements very slow. What are the parameters and the values for obtain a low specification with old devices ?

thanks a lot!

Comment: What is a "low specification"? Do you mean low delay?

Comment: the configuration for minimum performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the quality of the video by `motion.conf` file. I mean, decrease these values:

```
width 280  
height 320 
stream_maxrate 90
```

Also, it would be better if you disable some functions like `stream_motion off`. Additionally, check `minimum_gap 0` that the value is "0".

Check [THIS](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html) link out. It could be useful if you reduce the qualities and turn off unusable functions.